# python re match groups

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract some fields from string, however I am not sure how many are they.
I used regexp however, there are some problems which I do not understand.

for example:

```
  199  -> (199)
  199,200  -> (199,200)
  300,20,500 -> (300,20, 500)
```

I tried it, however somewhat I can not get this to work. 
Hope anyone can give me some advises. I will appreciate.

the regex I tried:

```
>>> re.match('^(\d+,)*(\d+)$', '20,59,199,300').groups()
('199,', '300')
// in this, I do not really care about ',' since I could use .strip(',') to trim that.
```

I did some google:  and tried to use re.findall, but I am not sure how do I get this:

```
>>> re.findall('^(\d+,)*(\d+)$', '20,59,199,300')
[('199,', '300')]
```

------------------------------------------------------update

I realize without telling the whole story, this question can be confusing. 
basically I want to validate syntax that defined in crontab (or similar)

I create a array for _VALID_EXPRESSION: it is a nested tuples.

```
 (field_1,
  field_2,
 )
```

for each field_1, it has two tuples,

```
 field_1:   ((0,59),        (r'....', r'....'))
            valid_value   valid_format
```

in my code, it looks like this:

```
_VALID_EXPRESSION =  \
 12     (((0, 59), (r'^\*$', r'^\*/(\d+)$', r'^(\d+)-(\d+)$',
 13                 r'^(\d+)-(\d+)/(\d+)$', r'^(\d+,)*(\d+)$')),   # second
 14      ((0, 59), (r'^\*$', r'^\*\/(\d+)$', r'^(\d+)-(\d+)$',
 15                 r'^(\d+)-(\d+)/(\d+)$', r'^(\d+,)*(\d+)$')),   # minute
 16        .... )
```

in my parse function, all I have to do is just extract all the groups and see if they are within the valid value.

one of regexp I need is that it is able to correctly match this string '50,200,300' and extract all the numbers in this case. (I could use split() of course, however, it will betray my original intention. so, I dislike that idea. )

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Besides the fact that it makes answerers think you're working hard and not just looking for a solution, it also lets us show you what you're getting wrong, find an answer that fits in with what you understand, etc.

Comment: In your question, you've got `'199' or '199,200' or '300,20,500'` all marked as a single piece of code. Is that the actual source string, or just `199,200`? If it's the latter… why are you trying to match anything? If you just want to match the whole thing, you don't need regex for that…

Comment: Your question is still vague. Do you want the string `(199,200)` in the second example? If so, what's wrong with just `({}).format(s)`? And what are those other rules you're talking about which can't be `split(',')` the same way as these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution with a regex is this:

```
r"(\d+,?)"
```

You can use `findall` to get the `300,`, `20,`, and `500` that you want. Or, if you don't want the commas:

```
r"(\d+),?"
```

This matches a group of 1 or more digits, followed by 0 or 1 commas (not in the group).

Either way:

```
>>> s = '300,20,500'
>>> r = re.compile(r"(\d+),?")
>>> r.findall(s)
['300', '20', '500']
```

However, as Sahil Grover points out, if those are your input strings, this is equivalent to just calling `s.split(',')`. If your input strings might have non-digits, then this will ensure you only match digit strings, but even that would probably be simpler as `filter(str.isdigit, s.split(','))`.

If you want a `tuple` of `int`s instead of a `list` of `str`s:

```
>>> tuple(map(int, r.findall(s)))
(300, 20, 500)
```

If you find comprehensions/generator expressions easier to read than `map`/`filter` calls:

```
>>> tuple(int(x) for x in r.findall(s))
(300, 20, 500)
```

Or, more simply:

```
>>> tuple(int(x) for x in s.split(',') if x.isdigit())
(300, 20, 500)
```

And if you want the string `(300, 20, 500)`, while you can of course do that by just calling `repr` on the `tuple`, there's a much easier way to get that:

```
>>> '(' + s + ')'
'(300, 20, 500)'
```

---

Your original regex:

```
'^(\d+,)*(\d+)$'
```

… is going to return exactly two groups, because you have exactly two groups in the pattern. And, since you're explicitly wrapping it in `^` and `$`, it has to match the entire string, so `findall` isn't going to help you here—it's going to find the exact same one match (of two groups) as `match`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a string.split?

```
numbers = targetstr.split(',')
```

Comment: How does that help? That'll give you `'199' or '199`, and `200' or '300`, and `20`, and `500'`.

Comment: I want to be as much generic as possible, because my other rule are using different regexp which can not be split as you suggested. if I use split for this case, I have to add a if-else statement which I do not really like.

Comment: @lightmanhk: Show us the actual input strings, exactly as they appear in your code, and with enough variety to show us all of the cases, and with the expected output. Otherwise, we have to read your mind to figure out what you want.

Comment: I might not have understood exactly what you were looking for.  As abarnert has suggested, we may need some additional info.

Comment: @SahilGrover: The more the OP writes, the more I suspect you _have_ understood what he's looking for, but he just doesn't realize it…